# Does appleutd@xmr3.com belong to the Apple up to date program?

Tags: macos, email, upgrade

I applied for the apple up to date program through their site and got now the e-mail with a password protected pdf attachment in it. Xmr3 doesn't really sound like apple. Has anybody some additional info on this?

NOTE: I didn't visit their site because the WOT add-on in safari rated the website with a poor reputation score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Offical Answer is that OS X Codes are sent through the domain xmr3.com (I suspect that he meant the sender appleutd@xmr3.com)

Source: I first called the Apple Support hotline and they said that I must contact the iTunes Store through express lane on theyr site. Express Lane didn't work at that moment so I went through the contact sheet http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact.html and got my answer.

Comment: Where is it documented that Apple officially sends program emails through xm3.com?

Comment: I don't know. Like I said, I went through the official apple.com contact sheet and got the e-mail message that the domain is used by apple to send program codes. I opened the pdf and the activation code did work. So from my view the domain has to be valid because 1. The code worked and I got my upgrade and 2. An official apple.com email answer in my language did approve xmr3.com. Yes, I do hate when companies ( MegaCorps ;) ) do use the cdn's domain names instead of their original domain name, it's a real PITA for the non involved people :(

Comment: Sorry for the editing and deleting, had to edit a typo

Answer (score 8):

I wonder if you signed up for their Up to Date Program on a web page pretending to be the Apple website. That PDF is most likely a scam, do not open it--It could execute some malicious code. In the last seven years I have yet to see e-mail communication from Apple that does *not* come from **apple.com**. Also, I think all of their invoicing is done by using HTML-formatted e-mail messages sent to your Apple ID, not PDF's. Hope this helps.

Comment: The real Up to Date signup page is here: http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/

Comment: Yup. xmr3.com is a malicious spammer domain. The site is actually "blocked" by Google Chrome due to security issues.

Comment: The only way I would expect a legitimate email to come **through** xmr3.com would be if your email hosting was through that domain. There is no way apple would contract to send mail from a non-official domain like this. Given the years of precedent for Apple never releasing software through a non-Apple domain - I would wait for an official press release from them before assuming someone stating otherwise was seen as credible.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that xmr3.com is a spammer domain. Google "xmr3.com spam" and you'll get a large number of links to scams that have run through that domain over the years.

I can't remember the last time, if ever, Apple has sent out a password protected PDF. Best not to mess with it.

I suggest you [call AppleCare](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57) to make sure that you are properly signed up for the Apple Up to Date program.

Answer (score -2):

appleutd@xmr3.com is not a scam. I received an email containing encrypted PDF. The email said password to unlock the PDF will follow and today it did. I unlocked the PDF and it contained the redeem code also it contained the reference number i got when submitting the up to date form. That number matched. Redeem code worked.

Comment: Even if it's not a scam - it's clearly not part of Apple's program for updating OS. Users beware.